# Inserting a node in BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert nodes in my custom BST.The first time the insertData method is called , the new node is correctly inserted as the root.The problem is occuring in the second and subsequent calls.

Below is My code :

1.The Node Class =

```
package ishan.trees.tree;

class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

private int data;
public int getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Node getLeftChild() {
    return leftChild;
}

public void setLeftChild(Node leftChild) {
    this.leftChild = leftChild;
}

public Node getRightChild() {
    return rightChild;
}

public void setRightChild(Node rightChild) {
    this.rightChild = rightChild;
}

private Node leftChild;
private Node rightChild;

public Node(int data,Node leftChild,Node rightChild)
{
    this.data=data;
    this.leftChild=leftChild;
    this.rightChild=rightChild;

}

@Override
public int compareTo(Node o) {
    if(o.getData() > this.data)
    return -1;

    if(o.getData() < this.data)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
}
```

The Tree Class =

```
package ishan.trees.tree;

public class Tree {

private Node root=null;

public Node getRoot() {
    return root;
}

public void insertData(int data)
{
    Node node=new Node(data,null,null);
    insert(node,this.root);

}

private Node insert(Comparable<Node> node,Node root1)
{
        if(root1==null)
        {//insert as first element ie root
            this.root=new Node(((Node)node).getData(),null,null);
        }
        else if(node.compareTo(root1) <0)
        {
            root1.setLeftChild(insert(node,root1.getLeftChild()));
        }
        else if(node.compareTo(root1) >0)
        {

            root1.setLeftChild(insert(node,root1.getRightChild()));
        }

 return root1;  
}
}
```

3.Main Class =

package ishan.trees.usage;

```
import ishan.trees.tree.Tree;

public class Usuage {

public static void main(String a[])
{
    Tree tree=new Tree();
    tree.insertData(10); //---------1
    tree.insertData(15); //---------2
    tree.insertData(9);  //---------3
    tree.insertData(4);  //---------4
}
}
```

when i debug the second call it is something like this:

insertData(15){
  insert(15,10)
}

which makes a call to the insert method as ---->

insert(15,null)

I get this null every time and this results in the current node replacing the root node.

I cant figure out why during the call , the root1 reference is null and not pointing to my root?

More Info :

Its during the call from insertData() to insert() . say During my second call to insertData(15) , i make a call to insert(15,this.root) -->insert(node,root1) . but this root1 reference turns out to be null.but when i inspect this.root it is referring to the correct root node..

Thanks!

Comment: Ok...so i was debugging it wrong.Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright here is dry run for your code,

Inserting 10.

When you insert first element, this API `insert` creates a new root for you as per your code  and sets it value to 10,

now second insertion makes it interesting, watch what happenes

StackTrace

```
insertData(15);
insert(node,root) // here root is your actuall root, originally initialized when u inserted first

// it goes to last else if inside insert api
root1.setRightChild(insert(node,root1.getRightChild())); // see now, this apis actually calls insert again, coz new node value was greater then root value

// this is how next stack trace will look like, as root right child was null
insert(node,null); // observer second argument is null again
```

now as per your Insert code will end up creating root again(root1 argument is null, first condition is executed), discarding previously defined root. this is what is causing your issue you are overriding your root again and again.

Answer (score 1):

After inserting first node i.e root, left and right node will be null. Next time while inserting left or right child node you are not checking that condition.

```
private Node insert(Comparable<Node> node,Node root1)
{
    if(root1==null)
    {//insert as first element ie root
        this.root=new Node(((Node)node).getData(),null,null);
    }
    else if(node.compareTo(root1) <0)
    {
        if(root1.getLeftChild()==null)
            root1.setLeftChild(node);
        else 
            root1.setLeftChild(insert(node,root1.getLeftChild()));
    }
    else if(node.compareTo(root1) >0)
    {

        if(root1.getRightChild()==null)
            root1.setRightChild(node);
        else 
            root1.setRightChild(insert(node,root1.getRightChild()));
    }

return root1;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is not the question.Its during the call from insertData() to insert() . During my second call to insertData(15) , i make a call to insert(15,this.root) -->insert(node,root1) . but this root1 reference turns out to be null.but when i inspect this.root it is referring to the correct root node..

Comment: its fulfilling `if(root1==null)` condition inside `insert` ?

Comment: For a better approach you can refer to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31994/creating-a-binary-search-tree